# Solr sort email field

Tags: email, sorting, solr

I have these emails : "jack@gmail.com", "jack1@gmail.com".
I want to sort them

The Solr will return the following result:

> jack1@gmail.com
>   jack@gmail.com

I think the correct sort result should be:

> jack@gmail.com
>   jack1@gmail.com

The configuration like this:

```
 <field name="email" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Anyone could help?

The following is solr response:

```
{ "responseHeader":{ "status":0, "QTime":0, "params":{ "sort":"advertiser_email_t asc", "indent":"true", "q":":", "wt":"json", "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[ { "advertiser_email_t":"ad111@qq.com", "id":"01df4dea-beb3-46fb-940b-78eda109503c" }, { "advertiser_email_t":"ad@qq.com", "id":"935de002-10e0-437f-a571-e74bb6646228" }, { "advertiser_email_t":"wang@qq.com", "id":"2a80935e-e520-4c3e-8d56-8e7b1096b372"}] } }
```

This is field definition:

> `<dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>`

This is field type  definition:

> ```
> <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
>       <analyzer type="index">
>         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
>         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
>         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
>       </analyzer>
>       <analyzer type="query">
>         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
>         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
>         <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
>         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
>       </analyzer>
>     </fieldType>
> ```

After changed field name to "email":

> {
>     "responseHeader": {
>       "status": 0,
>       "QTime": 0,
>       "params": {
>         "sort": "email asc",
>         "indent": "true",
>         "q": "*:*",
>         "_": "1383822359034",
>         "wt": "json"
>       }
>     },
>     "response": {
>       "numFound": 2,
>       "start": 0,
>       "docs": [
>         {
>           "email": "ad1@qq.com",
>           "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
>         },
>         {
>           "email": "ad@qq.com",
>           "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }

Comment: Could you add to your post how you perform the sort?

Comment: I passed sort field to Solr, The solr response is 

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "sort":"advertiser_email_t asc",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json",
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "advertiser_email_t":"ad111@qq.com",
        "id":"01df4dea-beb3-46fb-940b-78eda109503c"
   },
      {
        "advertiser_email_t":"ad@qq.com",
        "id":"935de002-10e0-437f-a571-e74bb6646228"
   },
      {
        "advertiser_email_t":"wang@qq.com",
        "id":"2a80935e-e520-4c3e-8d56-8e7b1096b372"}]
  }
}

Comment: By the response you posted, I can see that you try to sort by a field named `advertiser_email_t`, whose definition you did not share with us. What field type does it have? Could you post more of your schema.xml so that we can see your field types?

Comment: I add field and field type definitions

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query to sort by the field named `email` instead of `advertiser_email_t`. Something like

```
q=*:*&sort=email+asc
```

As according to the response you posted, you try to sort by the field named `advertiser_email_t`. This field is of the type `text_general` you also provided. That field type is tokenized and receives additional tokens by the mapped synonyms.

When reading in [the reference about sorting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-The%7B%7Bsort%7D%7DParameter) you can see that this cannot work

> > Solr can sort query responses according to document scores or the value of any indexed field with a single value (that is, any field whose attributes in schema.xml include multiValued="false" and indexed="true"), provided that:
> >
> > - the field is non-tokenized (that is, the field has no analyzer and its contents have been parsed into tokens, which would make the sorting inconsistent), or
> > - the field uses an analyzer (such as the KeywordTokenizer) that produces only a single term.

But your field named `email` is fine. It is of type string, which is sortable.

Comment: The problem still exists after changed field name to "email" the solr response be added